# Using Moose with Test::Class - problems with constructor

Tags: perl, moose

I'm refactoring a test suite built on [`Test::Class`](http://search.cpan.org/~adie/Test-Class-0.38/lib/Test/Class.pm), and would like to take advantage of such [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0604/lib/Moose.pm) niceties as [Roles](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0604/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod), both in the base test class, and in some of the test classes

I have tried:

- Using [`MooseX::NonMoose`](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0604/lib/Moose/Manual/MooseX.pod#MooseX%3a%3aNonMoose) in the base test class
- Using `MooseX::InsideOut` in the base class
- Setting `make_immutable( inline_constructor => 0 );`

Though I have never used either of those [MooseX](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0604/lib/Moose.pm#The_MooseX%3a%3a_namespace) modules before and cannot be sure I used them correctly. In all my trials I have received the following error on running the test suite:

> Test::Class internals seem confused. Did you override new() in a
>   sub-class or via multiple inheritence?

Simple sample which produces this failure:

Base test class:

```
package My::Test::Class::Base;

use Moose;
use Test::Class::Most;

1;
```

A test class:

```
package Test::Package::Class;

use Moose;
use Test::Class::Most parent => 'My::Test::Class::Base';

sub blah : Tests() {
    my $test = shift;
    can_ok($test->class(), 'blah');
}

1;
```

Class being tested:

```
package Package::Class;

use Moose;

sub blah {
    my $self = shift;
    return 1;
}

1;
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that Test::Class doesn't want you to override its new() constructor, but Moose does just that. People keep asking me how to deal with this, so I recently wrote [Test::Class::Moose](https://github.com/Ovid/test-class-moose). It's currently only on Github because it's alpha, but it seems fairly reasonable. Note that like [Test::Class::Most](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aClass%3a%3aMost), the common testing functions are provided for you.

If you try it, please let me know and provide feedback so I can better know what people want.

If you want something on the CPAN, there are several alternatives.

- [Test::Sweet](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aSweet)

It uses [MooseX::Declare](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aDeclare). Many people don't like that.

- [Test::Routine](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aRoutine).

You might not find the syntax intuitive, but it seems like a fine module.

- [Test::Able](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aAble)

Same issue as Test::Routine.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was scrabbling about with MooseX::NonMoose etc to try and get moose to place nicely with the Test::Class constructor.  I'll have a play with Test::Class::Moose for my own projects, and get back to you.  This question was triggered by $work though; migrating this project from Test::Class to another test platform would be a fight against inertia and management (to get time to do it). Unless there's a dirty hack to get Test::Class and Moose to co-operate I guess I'm going to be role-less

Comment: nickisfat: you can use my [Role::Basic](https://metacpan.org/module/Role::Basic) module to get roles when you don't have Moose or alternatives. I confess I've never been quite happy with Role::Basic's interface, but it should do the trick.